# Simple Two class (binary) classification using deep learning in matlab for text detection

Tags: deep-learning, text-classification

im completely new to this area and specially in matlab. so I need to either train or use a pre trained model for text detection. I dont need it to recognize the text class I want it to just tell me if a region that i give it to the cllasifier is text ot not. and the text is in english and it could be in any form or fonts.

so we can say the images would be cropped or completely without background and i need to determin either its text or not.

my question is that is there such a pretrained model available somewhere?
or i have to train it myself?
if i should train it, how much data i need and how much time it takes on a laptop with these specs:

cpu : core i 7,

gpu: gtx-960m,

ram: 16gb

thanks in advance. im really short in time to do this so if there is any pre trained option available i will take that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are short in time and need to get started, I would recommend a plug&play OCR model like [tesseract](https://opensource.google/projects/tesseract)